# OSX Shell Script - deleting all desktop files

Tags: macos, shell

I am trying to delete all files on the Desktop of seperate users from my admin account using a shell script.

This is my code to delete (for student)

```
sudo rm /Users/student/Desktop/*
```

but i get an error:

```
rm: /Users/student/Desktop/*: No such file or directory
```

When i run the script it prompts me for the Admin pass, then errors out.
Is using the Desktop/* appropriate? any tips? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path expansion is done *before* `sudo` is executed. This means, it is done with the access rights of the current user and if you may not access `/Users/student/Desktop` then the expansion fails. Instead, do this:

```
sudo bash -c "rm /Users/student/Desktop/*"
```

This way the path expansion is done with the elevated rights granted by `sudo`. You might need to do `rm -r` if there are any directories/bundles on the desktop.